# How to set options for existing product attribute via code?

Tags: magento, attributes

I have some existing product attribute, and it already has some values.
I want to set new options for it (set, not add).

There is no ability to do this via **updateAttribute**.
It is possible to add new options using **addAttributeOption** method, but it just adds new options.

But how can I remove old options, and add new?

Comment: what is the difference between add and set in your question context ?

Comment: set will replace all existing options, add - just adds new options

Comment: You can add more options by change manually database.

Comment: Please describe in depth what you're trying to do.

Comment: he is perfectly clear what he wants to do. i know because i want to do the same thing but also dont know how.
if any1 of there guys would know the answer they wouldnt ask you to "describe in depth"...

Answer (score 0):

You need to be more clear about what type of attribute you are talking about and what you mean by options. I believe you are talking about a select attribute.